# Adjusting Wide Multicolumn Table to Fit Within Page Margins

Tags: tables, margins, multicolumn

I've created a table in LaTeX using the booktabs package, but it exceeds the page margins when compiled. The table uses multicolumns. I need to maintain the readability of the content while ensuring that it fits within the standard page margins. How can I adjust the table or the document layout to prevent the overflow?"

Here is the MWE that replicates the problem.

```
 \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article} 
 \usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage{booktabs} 
 \usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{tabulary}
 \usepackage{tabularx}
 \usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{multirow}

 \begin{document}



\begin{table}[!ht]
\begin{center}
\caption{CIPS Panel Unit Root Tests}
 \label{tab:table_CIPS}
 \vspace{.5cm}
\begin{tabular}{lcccccc}
\toprule
\toprule
   & \multicolumn {2}{c}{Intercept} & \multicolumn {2}{c}{Intercept +\ Trend }& 
 \multicolumn {2}{c}{Intercept +\ First Difference } \\
 \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
 \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
  \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
     &\multicolumn{1}{c}{CADF_{i}(0)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{CADF_{i}(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c} 
  {CADF_{i}(0)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{CADF_{i}(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{CADF_{i} 
  (0)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{CADF_{i}(1)}\\
      \cmidrule{2-5}
        ln nonresource FDI          &       -1.86**&        0.92  &      -16.23***  &       
   0.098***\\                         
 ln population               &       -1.86**&        0.92  &      -16.23***  &       
  0.098***\\                       
     ln human capital            &       -1.86**&        0.92  &      -16.23***  &       
  0.098***\\
     ln GDP per capita $(t = 1)$ &       -1.86**&        0.92  &      -16.23***  &       
    0.098***\\            
    ln GDP surrounding market potential        &       -1.86**&        0.92     &      
-16.23***  &       0.098***\\   
   Government share of GDP \times 100         &       -1.86**&        0.92     &      -16.23***  &       0.098***\\   
       ln hydrocarbon resource rents (t \times 1) & -1.86**      &        0.92     &      -16.23***  &       0.098***\\
 ln nonresource FDI (i \times 1)            & -1.86**      &        0.92     &      -16.23***  &       0.098***\\
\bottomrule 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
 \end{center}
  {\footnotesize
   {H0: All series are nonstationary. The statistics are the standardized version of the $CIPS_(p)$ statistic for an unbalanced panel. The $CIPS_(p)$ statistic is the cross-section average of the cross sectionally augmented Dickey-Fuller test statistic $(CADF_{i}(p)))$. Following Pesaran (2007), extreme t values are truncated to avoid any undue influence of extreme outcomes, because t is small (10–20). *$p<0.1$, **$p<0.05$, ***$p<0.01$. For the first difference of ln population, we also reject the null if we restrict the sample to a balanced panel.}}
 \end{table}
  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you could make the headings on two lines so Intercept +\ First Difference  wasn't so wide or be less verbose in the first column so it's not so wide you could also use `@{}` as first and last entry in the column spec so the column padding is removed from the outer edges

Comment: Worst case, replace the first column iwht a multiline (p) column.

Answer (score 1):

What about putting it sideways?

I've used `threeparttable` for the table notes:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[para]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{CIPS Panel Unit Root Tests}
 \label{tab:table_CIPS}
\begin{tabular}{lcccccc}
\toprule
\toprule
   & \multicolumn {2}{c}{Intercept} & \multicolumn {2}{c}{Intercept +\ Trend }& 
 \multicolumn {2}{c}{Intercept +\ First Difference } \\
 \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
 \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
  \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
     &\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\textrm{CADF}_{i}(0)$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\textrm{CADF}_{i}(1)$}&\multicolumn{1}{c} 
  {$\textrm{CADF}_{i}(0)$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\textrm{CADF}_{i}(1)$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\textrm{CADF}_{i} 
  (0)$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\textrm{CADF}_{i}(1)$}\\
      \cmidrule{2-7}
        ln nonresource FDI          &       -1.86**&        0.92  &      -16.23***  &       
   0.098***\\                         
 ln population               &       -1.86**&        0.92  &      -16.23***  &       
  0.098***\\                       
     ln human capital            &       -1.86**&        0.92  &      -16.23***  &       
  0.098***\\
     ln GDP per capita $(t = 1)$ &       -1.86**&        0.92  &      -16.23***  &       
    0.098***\\            
    ln GDP surrounding market potential        &       -1.86**&        0.92     &      
-16.23***  &       0.098***\\   
   Government share of GDP $\times$ 100         &       -1.86**&        0.92     &      -16.23***  &       0.098***\\   
       ln hydrocarbon resource rents (t $\times$ 1) & -1.86**      &        0.92     &      -16.23***  &       0.098***\\
 ln nonresource FDI (i $\times$ 1)            & -1.86**      &        0.92     &      -16.23***  &       0.098***\\
\bottomrule 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item H0: All series are nonstationary. The statistics are the standardized version of the $CIPS_(p)$ statistic for an unbalanced panel. The $CIPS_(p)$ statistic is the cross-section average of the cross sectionally augmented Dickey-Fuller test statistic $(CADF_{i}(p)))$. Following Pesaran (2007), extreme t values are truncated to avoid any undue influence of extreme outcomes, because t is small (10–20). *$p<0.1$, **$p<0.05$, ***$p<0.01$. For the first difference of ln population, we also reject the null if we restrict the sample to a balanced panel.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image]